# Number of recursive calls for recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm, recursion, math, complexity-theory, matrix-multiplication

I'm studying for an algorithms and data structures exam and came across this question in a past paper:

[Question background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPRU1.png)

[Actual question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrFve.png)

Note there is an error in the handout I think, the range of k should be from i to j not 1 to j, otherwise there is an infinite loop, which I guess is at least 2^n calls.

I've been going at it for a while and I have made some progress, but ultimately I have no clue where to go from here and there are no marking schemes available. I think I'll need to use the master theorem but can't figure out how to get it in the right shape. Any help would be appreciated even it it's just a link to a Wikipedia article that may be related.

I've tried formulating Ω(m[i,j]) as the sum of k = i+1 to j-1 (inclusive) of (2 + Ω(m[i,k]) + Ω(m[k, j])) which i think is correct, but after trying to simplify it I'm completely lost.

Comment: Use induction over n.

Comment: It's possible to show by induction that a naive implementation of the algorithm grows *more quickly* than `2^n` - in fact the number of calls would be exactly `3^(n-1)`. I suspect it would only scale as `ϴ(2^n)` with memoization.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog & @n thanks! I managed to get it in terms of n and prove the same ϴ(3^(n-1)). Don't know why I was overcomplicating it so much.